# $scope.varaiable cannot be accessed inside jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

variable not going to be accessed inside a jquery function? Cause I tried to create a scope variable with strings and test if it were to show in the console but it just returns the scope variable as undefined.

NOTE: The jquery code I have provided below is inside the angularjs controller.

```
$('body').on('click', '#editFunc', function(e) {

        var clickedEdit = $(this);
        var id = clickedEdit.attr("data-id");
        var url = "/editProfiles?applicant_id=" + id;
        var editData = {
                editId: id
        }
        
        $http.get('/getEditProfilesData/', {params: editData}).then(function(response) {
            
            $scope.stringXample = "Yeh";
            var appData = response.data;
            console.log(appData);
            //$(location).attr('href', url);
            
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi, interesting, how is `$scope` defined? Perhaps you intend to use `$(this)`?

Comment: Hi, I think you like to access ```$scope.stringXample``` outside this jQuery function. Possible to create jsfiddle example to better under standing.

Comment: I have to use $scope so I can access what's suppose to be $scope.appData and display in an input field. But for some reason when I try to log $scope.StringXample it returns that StringXample isn't defined.

Comment: Bigger question is why are you making event bindings with jQuery instead of angular?

Comment: Because I'm using datatables and the only way I know for me to do event binding in datatables is with jquery and javascript. So I thought there would be a way for me to implement it through jquery since I have already done it this way.

Comment: But how would I then get the data I got from my request (inside $http) if I were to have scope declared out of jquery?

Comment: Why you do not use `ng-click="vm.editProfile(this)"`?

Comment: Could you post code that includes the controller.  There's not enough detail there to answer your question.

Comment: Also, you haven't said which variable can't be accessed, just that some variable can't be.  Here you're logging `appData`, which is nothing to do with the `$scope` object.